# Write a function that can accept values and any kind of iteratable type

Tags: python, list, numpy, iterator

I wonder if it is possible to write the following code in a very pythonic way.

The code is simplified. It should accept a single values for each input, as well as a sequence or a numpy array. The problem is that a single value does not have any `len()` argument. Currently I am checking if the type is either `numpy array` or a `list`.

However in the future, there might be different data representations that will be iterated, like a panda-array or similar. This would lead to a further change of code and a longer if-statement.

It would be very nice if it is possible to check if the input is iterable or not, so that the code will be dynamic for the future.

Simplified example code:

```
import numpy as np


def test(a,b):
    c = []
    if type(a) != type(b):
        return None;

    if type(a) is np.ndarray or type(a) is list:
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            c.append(a[i] + b[i])
    else:
        c = a + b
  
    return c
        
A = test(1,2)
B = test([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
C = test(np.asarray([1,2,3]),np.asarray([1,2,3]))
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you're working with numpy, one option is just to wrap every input with `np.asanyarray`, and then you're left with a numpy array for scalars, lists, and arrays

Comment: Can you give a less contrived example? Do you care what type `B` is? Must it be `list`, or can it also be `np.ndarray`?

Comment: There's plenty of other things in this code that are not Pythonic. For instance, you should *never* iterate over `range(len(something))`. In your case, you should use `zip(a, b)`, so that whole block could just be `c = [first + second for first, second in zip(a, b)]`.

Comment: This looks like a dispatch problem in general. You can try a library called multipledispatch https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if both element have the `__iter__` method.

```
def test(a, b):
    if not hasattr(a, '__iter__') and not hasattr(b, '__iter__'):
        return a + b
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]  # Let zip() raise the TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10, you can use pattern matching and abstract base classes:

```py
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable
>>> def test(a, b):
...     match (a, b):
...             case (Iterable(), Iterable()):
...                     return [x + y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
...             case _:
...                     return a + b
... 
>>> test([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
>>> test(1,2)
3
```

And you might add the case

```py
case (np.ndarray(), np.ndarray()):
    return list(a + b)
```

for efficiency.  Although if you use Numpy anyways, I'd go with @Eric's recommendation of

```py
def test(a, b):
    return np.asanyarray(a) + np.asanyarray(b)
```